# Type 'FundsVC' does not conform to protocol 'STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate' in Swift while "Stripe" integration

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I am using `"Stripe"` payment gateway in my application.. for that i have registered in Stripe account and got **test and secret keys**

and my code is:

```
 import Stripe

 class FundsVC: UIViewController, STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate //here getting an error {

 @IBAction func stripePaymentBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    let config = STPPaymentConfiguration.shared()//here getting second error
    config.requiredBillingAddressFields = .full
    let viewController = STPAddCardViewController(configuration: config, theme: STPTheme.default())
    viewController.delegate = self
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
    present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}


//MARK:- STPAdd Card Controller Delegate
func addCardViewControllerDidCancel(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func addCardViewController(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController, didCreateToken token: STPToken, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {
    
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
}
```

please do help

**errors**

> 'WithdrawFundsVC' does not conform to protocol 'STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate'

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'STPPaymentConfiguration'

**EDIT**

i have updated code like this:

```
func addCardViewControllerDidCancel(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
 }

@objc
func addCardViewController(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController, didCreatePaymentMethod paymentMethod: STPPaymentMethod, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**o/p** **here Done button is not enable why?**

[image]

Comment: There should be a little circle on the error message, clicking it will give you the option to fix the error, which in this case means adding the necessary properties and method signatures. For the second one, just remove the `()`

Comment: I've redacted your `defaultPublishableKey` but you should re-generate it, since anybody could have seen it, and will live in the edit history of your question.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez, yes i can remove `()` but in top i am not getting circle i am getting cross mark.. unable to get suggestions.. what could be the issue.. any idea?

Comment: I would type `addCardViewController` in your class and see what the auto-complete tries to generate, if the compiler things anything is missing, it should show up on that list. If that doesn't work I'd first try cleaning the project (Cmd + K) and if that doesn't work either I would clear DerivedData.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez please do help here, i got stuck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69121658/how-to-show-pay-instead-of-done-in-stpaddcardviewcontroller-in-stripe-in-swi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are following old tutorial for stripe implementation that is compatible with stripe old pod but you are using latest stripe version .
According to latest **STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate** documentation you should need these two method for its conformance

```
addCardViewControllerDidCancel(_:)
addCardViewController(_:didCreatePaymentMethod:completion:)
```

but you are implementing  method

```
addCardViewController(_:didCreateToken:completion:)
```

which is deprecated in latest version.
you need to change your implementation according to new version . if you still want to use old implementation then fix pod version to **15.0.0** in your pod file . if you encounter  any error than change pod version to **15.0.1**.

Comment: i have edited my post with updated code.. now `why Done button is disable`.. i am not able to select Done button

Comment: plz one check the o/p.. my done button is disable.. why?.. could you help

Comment: you are using wrong  card expiry date . it should be higher than current date . i.e you are using date 04/9 that is april 2009(expired) and now we are in 09/21. just use date  above 09/21. try with 10/21.

Comment: please try to answer here, i got stuck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69121658/how-to-show-pay-instead-of-done-in-stpaddcardviewcontroller-in-stripe-in-swi